# Handling brownouts during external flash writes

Tags: microcontroller, power, flash

What techniques should be applied for writing flash in systems that have inherently unreliable power? Is there any good reading material on the subject?

If I have a microcontroller writing sensor data intermittently to external flash, and there's a brownout during one of the writes (and the whole system resets), what precautions should be taken?

I assume CRC is a must, but what else should be done?

Comment: Can you not use large capacitors (or maybe supercaps) with diodes to prevent the cap from leaking charge back onto the line? How long of a brownout are we talking? Like fractions of a second or minutes on end?

Comment: What @Toor said.  If you can influence the hardware design, make sure there's enough energy in the caps to gracefully halt the flash write.

Comment: Really good question.  We fill the memory with known illegal values and overwrite them as we go.  When a reset occurs, we check to see what type of reset has occurred, and the scan through the memory to find the last written location and flag or delete it.

Comment: That also depends on what you are writing. Is it some data you are receiving from an external source? Is it critical data you have gathered internally (like some measurement statistics)? There are different approaches based on the importance of the data.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead the needed erase of pages in flash makes multiple writing usually not possible (and pages tend to be 256 bytes or larger), so you are stuck with the FFs of an erased flash.

Comment: raw flash, or (e)mmc?

Comment: @Arsenal the data is pretty important and is gathered internally, and losing it would be less than ideal.

Comment: @Jasen raw flash (I think), talking over spi

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends on the kind of data you are handling which kind of precautions you ought to take.

An important thing you might want to investigate beforehand is: what kind of failures will you encounter because of a brown out, depending on which operation is active (write or erase). Will just the page you are using be affected or might there be more pages affected and corrupted. I've seen wild things with ICs, so I won't make a prediction here.

Another important thing to think about is flash endurance. Flash cells only have a limited lifetime. So make sure that your flash is able to handle the amount of erase/write cycles you are expecting it to have. You might need some sort of rotation or a bigger flash for the rotation if it's too much. An EEPROM has higher endurance typically, so maybe change to that.

---

**Critical data**

(i.e. the device is dead when the data gets corrupted)

For this kind of data, the first thing to do is to evaluate if it actually has to be written at any time during the device lifetime other than during calibration (for example) when the data is generated. During that time you should be able to provide a stable power source.

If critical data has to be written I'd go for several things:

1. Keep multiple (three or more) copies in different pages
2. the copies should be write-protect-able independent of each other to make sure an accidental delete is not likely
3. Make one copy the inverse of the data stored
4. each copy has it's own checksum (CRC-32 or something depending on the length of the data involved)
5. Choose an error correction algorithm suited for your application

Examples of algorithms you might choose:

- The data includes a counter to indicate the version of the data, each data gets read and the one with the highest counter with a valid checksum gets chosen, the other copies get overwritten with that data.
- All data gets read and a two out of three vote gets cast (two sets must be the same with a valid checksum) and the different data gets overwritten, consider what happens if you have one set written, one set deleted and one old set, so you might want to have four sets

---

**Internally generated data**

(i.e measurement data)

For this kind of data I'd choose a slightly different approach than the critical data route.

It's kind of like the first algorithm but a bit relaxed. If you have a new data set available, overwrite the oldest data set. It's like a rolling log. To get the correct set, just read the data sets and choose the one with the highest counter and a valid checksum.

Using the write protection intelligently and scattering the data (don't just increment the page with a new data set) will help to preserve the last data set.

Think about what happens if the counter overflows (0 can be larger than 255 in a way).

---

**Received data**

(i.e. firmware update)

For data which you are receiving, you need a protocol which supports resuming the transmission at any given point. Usually I'd go for checksums for each page written. If the outtakes are likely to happen frequently, maybe do two checksums per page.

Then to resume the operation, read the flash and check the checksums until it doesn't match anymore and tell the sender to resume transmission after the last valid byte.

Comment: I guess I wrote a general answer and not a specific one...

Answer (score 1):

> What techniques should be applied for writing flash in systems that have inherently unreliable power?
>
> If I have a microcontroller writing sensor data intermittently to
>   external flash, and there's a brownout during one of the writes (and
>   the whole system resets), what precautions should be taken?

While it's obvious, as other answers and comments have largely taken a "what to
 do to lessen impact" approach, I'll comment on the approach 'from the other direction'.

**Summary: Don't let it happen!**

Inherently unreliable overall system power need not imply unreliable system operation.
Fail **safe** is almost always an option.
Almost.

The cost of some of the following in resource and design effort may start to be annoying, but it's the cost of doing business if you want business to be done properly.
The effort in reliably preventing problems happening may well be far less than arranging reliable recovery and mitigation schemes to deal with problems that have been "allowed" to happen.  Anti-brownout is about ensuring an in-spec DC supply for milliseconds to seconds and in spec data and control line levels.
How hard can it be?
Very.
Sometimes. :-) :-(
But the alternative can be harder.

Brownout is a condition with known cause - even when the cause is unknown :-).
While lightning strike and intruder-with-TASER* are probably beyond being "designable for", most other things aren't.  When the system is critical enough it should be possible without vast expense to improve brownout protection to the "act of God" level.
(* A well known issue in security systems in some countries, I'm told)

Methods are 'obvious enough'. Some of the following are "system falls over under extreme provocation" rather than brownout per se - but the two overlap well enough to mix them here. An incomplete list that gives the general idea would include -

- Adequate holdup filter capacitors.
- Supercap if necessary for long writes.
- Maybe battery backup for even longer writes.
  A backup battery system could be designed to never ever be needed except in exceptional circumstances, so that battery sizing can be very small and a whole-of-system-lifetime battery can be cheaply employed.
- Adequate noise filtering both at critical components and in system power rail generally to prevent noise effects at each IC and from propagating across the system.
- Adequate EMC shielding.
- Scrupulous attention to system design.   An incomplete list would include -

  - Buffers that adequately maintain signal and data lines within data sheet design limits.
  - No arrangements that allow a signal line noise pulse to cause IC body diodes to conduct beyond the pico-amp level.
  - Adequate interface slew rate filtering (usually minimal) to ensure that read or write timings are not violated causing data corruption.
  - No dependence on read after write data integrity issues that fail in marginal noise conditions.
  - ...

Answer (score 1):

Write the bit that indicates that the record  is good last.

flash memory writes easily in one direction but reseting bits back to the unwritten condition needs a block erase.

so write the whole record and then as the last step write the bit that indicates that the record is good.

when reading skip any records that are missing the good bit, as they may be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I would answer to add a simple point I think others missed.

Whatever scheme you choose. **Test extensively**.

Brown out flash errors are relatively  rare occurance as it depends on the coincidence of multiple factors.

- Test many thousands of brownout cycles
- Test under random timeout conditions
- Run several at a time due to component variation
- Run at different load and evironment  conditions
- Run an index device that is continuously writing to flash during the test as a control

The severity depends on how critical this system is, for most applications 2-10k random brownout cycles on 3 or so samples is good enough.

You may also find that your design is already good enough for your needs, a week of testing to possibly  eliminate a respin may be worth it .